# make `emscripten` available via cmake

Tags: docker, cmake, clion, emscripten

I'm trying to use , but it is not available, so I'm using FetchContent on cmake to make it available, It worked for GSL and Googletest. But the emscripten simple doesn't build, and the emscripten-build folder is empty on the `cmake-build-debug-docker/_deps` folder.

The question is how to work with `emscripten` and cmake. I'm using docker from a docker file and Clion.

```
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
        googletest
        URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/609281088cfefc76f9d0ce82e1ff6c30cc3591e5.zip
)

FetchContent_Declare(
        emscripten
        URL https://github.com/emscripten-core/emsdk/archive/refs/heads/main.zip
)



# GSL: Guidelines Support Library
# In this example we are picking a specific tag.
# You can also pick a specific commit, if you need to.
FetchContent_Declare(
        GSL
        URL https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/archive/refs/heads/main.zip
)
# For Windows: Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker settings
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest emscripten GSL)

#if(NOT GSL_POPULATED)
if(GSL_POPULATED)
    #    FetchContent_Populate(GSL)
    # Store the old value of the 'BUILD_SHARED_LIBS'
    set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS_OLD ${BUILD_SHARED_LIBS})
    # Make subproject to use 'BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON' setting.
    set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON CACHE INTERNAL "Build SHARED libraries")

    add_subdirectory(${GSL_SOURCE_DIR} ${GSL_BINARY_DIR})
    
    # Restore the old value of the parameter
    set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ${BUILD_SHARED_LIBS_OLD} CACHE BOOL "Type of libraries to build" FORCE)
endif()
```

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk add --update gcc g++ git doxygen xz graphviz clang gdb cmake make ninja autoconf automake dos2unix tar rsync python2 python3 && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/cache/apk/*


RUN git clone https://github.com/emscripten-core/emsdk.git

RUN cd emsdk

CMD ls emsdk
# Enter that directory
CMD cd emsdk
CMD ls

## Download and install the latest SDK tools.
RUN ["./emsdk/emsdk", "install", "tot"]

# Make the "latest" SDK "active" for the current user. (writes .emscripten file)
RUN ["./emsdk/emsdk", "activate", "tot"]

# Activate PATH and other environment variables in the current terminal
RUN source ./emsdk/emsdk_env.sh
```

Comment: If you're using Docker anyway, you should set up your dependencies there, not in the CMakeLists.txt... prefer `find_package`. To use emscripten, one generally sets the `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` variable at the command line to the EMSDK toolchain.

Comment: How can I set the dependencies for emscripten on docker then?

Comment: ```FROM alpine

RUN apk add --update gcc g++ git doxygen xz graphviz clang gdb cmake-3.16.3 make ninja autoconf automake dos2unix tar rsync python3 && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/cache/apk/*```

Comment: This is my basic docker file. How to set up the emscripten dependencies there so I can use `#include <emscripten.h>`?